# Modifying 3d model using code

Tags: 3d, xna, modeling, kinect

I am building a piece of software that uses Kinect to measure a user.  I want to roughly display these results on screen in the form of a 3d Model.

Essentially what I want to do is modify a 3d model using parameters (waist, height, chest, hips) to make it represent the user.

I am using XNA and ideally would like to make the modifications in xna

Any ideas how to go about this, or any pointers as to where to start researching would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dunno much about the kinect api but it was built to render a 'bone structure' sort of like optical motion capture. Probably looking into that, hierarchical bone systems, skinning/rigging, linear blending ( for clean muscle deformation) and quaternion angles ( to avoid gimbal lock ) is a good start..

Comment: When you say "modify the 3d model", are you meaning causing it to bend at the joints and stuff, or are you meaning you want to make the model taller/shorter, fatter/skinnier, etc... to match the person on camera?? Or both?

Comment: Steve, i want to make it taller, shorter, fatter, thinner. Im not too fussed about animation as such. I totally didnt explain it well! Kinda like in the sims where u can make ur sims fatter/thinner using the sliders!

Comment: @Ewen the term "animation" is used loosely and can include deformation like making a figure fatter or thinner.  The basic idea is the same - vertices are attached to bones (usually with weighting to smooth things out).  Unlike real bones, animation rig bones are stretchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique you're after is often referred to as "rigging", where a 3D model is attached to a skeleton which can be manipulated to animate it.

If you have the time, I'd recommend downloading the very good open source 3D modelling tool [blender](http://blender.org). Once you've got your head round the idiosyncratic interface, there are [many tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=blender%20rigging&btnK=Google%20Search&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=) out there, plus info on how to export from blender in a format XNA can use.

Creating a good rigged model is tricky though - you might want to get an experienced 3D animator to help.